# Connect R with OrientDB

Tags: r, connection, orientdb

Are there any R packages for connecting R to OrientDB?

For instance (maybe), something similar to the packages for MongoDB (RMongo, rmongodb). 
I searched a little on the web, but couldn't find anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look for Retrography https://github.com/retrography/OrientR . Right now it only supports a query function.